# Laravel eloquent eager loading limit error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have custom query where I try get professions users with 5 limit

**Code**

```
$professions = Profession::whereHas("users", function($q) use($query) {
    $q->where("professions.name", "like", "%$query%");
})->withCount('users')->with('users', function($q) {
    $q->take(5);
})->paginate(10);
```

Then get error with message:

> ErrorException: mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given

Why I get this error and how can be fixed this error?

I've read this [issue comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014#issuecomment-281725011) from github and tried but get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake at this line:

```
 $q->where("professions.name", "like", "%".$query."%");
```

You need to concatenate the variable.
You're getting this error because `with()` takes an associative array in order to constrain eager loads. Try:

```
$professions = Profession::whereHas("users", function($q) use($query) {
    $q->where("professions.name", "like", "%".$query."%");
})->withCount('users')->with(['users' => function($q) {
    $q->take(5);
}])->paginate(10);
```

Comment: When I remove part of code `->with('users', function($q) { $q->take(5); })` from my query all work correctly. Also when I remove callback from `->with('users')` I get all `users` list but when I try `limit()` or `take()` methods then get error.

Comment: @AndreasHunter I have found the answer I will update my answer.

Comment: Concatenation variable `$query` doesn't needed in my case too.

Comment: @AndreasHunter You're getting this error because `with()` takes an associative array in order to constrain eager loads.

Comment: Yes you're right. Now your answer code work to me @AmitSenjaliya